# How can i make a rigid body jump in godot without givign it the ability to fly

Tags: 2d, game-engine, godot, rigid-bodies, gdscript

I would have used a kinematic body but i want to add real life physics to my 2d object but it seems that i can literally fly by pressing the up key several times

```
extends RigidBody2D

var velocity = Vector2.ZERO

const GRAVITY = 35
const SPEED = 1000
const JUMPFORCE = -900

func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right"):
        apply_central_impulse(Vector2(1000,0))
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left"):
        apply_central_impulse(Vector2(-1000,0))
    if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up"):
        apply_central_impulse(Vector2(0,-1000))
```

Answer (score 2):

---

### With `test_motion`

I do not recommend handling this with the `RigidBody2D` collisions because not every collision means it is on the ground (e.g. could be hitting a wall or ceiling).

However, there is another way: you can use [`test_motion`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_rigidbody2d.html#class-rigidbody2d-method-test-motion). It returns true if a movement would result in a collision (without actuallyu moving, of course).

So use `test_motion` downwards, if it detects a collision, it means the `RigidBody2D` is on the ground:

```
if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up") and self.test_motion(Vector2(0, 1), false):
    apply_central_impulse(Vector2(0,-1000))
```

---

### With `RayCast2D`

Another simple setup is using `RayCast2D` instead. Position it to extend downwards from the the bottom of the `CollisionShape2D` or `CollisionPolygon2D` of the `RigidBody2D`. Make sure the `RayCast2D` is enabled. Then you can check if the `RayCast2D` is colliding to decide if the `RigidBody2D` can jump:

```
if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up") and $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
    apply_central_impulse(Vector2(0,-1000))
```

Consider that with the above method, if the `RayCast2D` fail to detect something, the `RigidBody2D` won't be able to jump. For example, if the `RayCast2D` is centered, but the `RigidBody2D` is only partially on the ground, such that the `RayCast2D` hits nothing.

---

### With `Area2D`

Another alternative is to use an `Area2D` instead of a `RayCast2D`. Which has the advantage of having its own `CollisionShape2D` or `CollisionPolygon2D`. You will need to keep count of bodies that enter or exist the `Area2D`:

```
var on_ground := 0

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body: Node) -> void:
    on_ground += 1

func _on_Area2D_body_exited(body: Node) -> void:
    on_ground -= 1
```

And of course, use that in your check to jump:

```
if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up") and on_ground > 0:
    apply_central_impulse(Vector2(0,-1000))
```

---

Finally I remind you that you have collision layers and collision masks. Using a `RayCast2D` or an `Area2D` would allow you to set a different mask than the one the `RigidBody2D` uses. Which is a way to specify that not all things that the `RigidBody2D` collides with, are things from which it can jump.

*I find `Area2D` to be more reliable and versatile. However, it is more work to setup.*

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add something in the answer by Theraot.
Here one signal by area2d can be avoided.

```
var on_ground := 0

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body: Node) -> void:
 on_ground = 0

if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up") and on_ground == 0:
 apply_central_impulse(Vector2(0,-1000))
 on_ground = 1
```

This works same as using both signals of body entered and exited.

Comment: If the player character is on a platform, since you handled body entered, it knows it is on the ground. Then if the character walks off the platform (so it is falling, not jumped), since you didn't handle body exited, the code does not know it is no longer on a platform. So it still lets you jump.