# How do I make enemies not fall from a platform?

Tags: godot

Currently, the enemies I made are able to "patrol" an area and change direction when they hit a wall.
I would like to put them on floating platforms without them falling off, how could I do that?

Here is the code that makes them change direction when they hit a wall:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    _velocity.y += gravity * delta
    if is_on_wall():
        _velocity.x *= -1.0
    _velocity.y = move_and_slide(_velocity, FLOOR_NORMAL).y
```

Comment: what do mean by falling off? is it sideways or up and down jitter?

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh Oh sorry, i should have specified. The game is a 2D side scroller and I want the enemies to turn around when they get to the end of a platform, instead of keep going and falling off. Hope what i'm trying to say is clear

Comment: add an empty game object at the end of the platform, have it coloured so you can identify them easily (you'll find this option in the inspector. when the charter collides with the object, flip em.

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh Oh i had thought about doing something like that lol. I just thought that there would have probably been a function that made it possible to recognize an empty tile and make the entity able to act upon that information. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: You can do it on the physics object, using a RayCast2D or an Area2D to detect if there is ground ahead. See [How can i make a rigid body jump in godot without givign it the ability to fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67404421/402022) - I know you are not asking about RigidBody2D, but the RayCast2D and Area2D solutions I suggest to detect ground for a RigidBody2D there can very easily be adapted for this (just don't use to them to check directly down, but off center at one side, and of course you don't use apply_central_impulse, but change velocity).

Comment: @Theraot the problem with a raycast approach is that you might hit walls and the ray cast would still detect the wall as ground and the character will end up running endlessly. Ray cast would work well for platforms with open ends.

Comment: you can just include the enemy in a group "enemy" and add an Area2D on the edge of the floating platform with a signal "body_entered" and on the script include a code if body.is_in_group("enemy"): include the code for change direction.

Comment: Excuse me @Theraot, but could you show me an example of how to use the RayCast2D to check if there's ground ahead? I haven't grasped on its function yet

Comment: @Theraot i've tried doing this but the enemy now stand still. Where am i supposed to place the raycast and what errors are in the code? `func _physics_process(delta):
 _velocity.y += gravity * delta
 if is_on_wall():
  _velocity.x *= -1.0
 _velocity.y = move_and_slide(_velocity, FLOOR_NORMAL).y
 
 if $RayCast2D.is_colliding() == true:
  _velocity.x *= -1.0
  $RayCast2D.position.x *= -1.0`

Answer (score 1):

On OP demand, here is how I would set this up using `RayCast2D`.

First of all, the `RayCast2D` will be a child of the `KinematicBody2D` and we need to position it to the side and pointing down. Also make sure the `RayCast2D` is enabled. As seen here:

[image: Godot window screenshot]

And for the code I'm using this:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

export var gravity:float = 100
var _velocity:Vector2 = Vector2.RIGHT * 100

const FLOOR_NORMAL:Vector2 = Vector2.UP

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    _velocity.y += gravity * delta
    _velocity.y = move_and_slide(_velocity, FLOOR_NORMAL).y
    if is_on_wall() or (is_on_floor() and !$RayCast2D.is_colliding()):
        _velocity.x *= -1.0
        $RayCast2D.position.x *= -1.0
```

To check for the hole, we want to verify that the `RayCast2D` is *NOT* colliding. If it is colliding, it means there is floor ahead. The check for `is_on_floor` is to avoid it changing direction in the air.

Also, I'm checking both conditions on a single statement. First to avoid repetition, and second because if there are two checks that can change the direction, and they both change the direction… The result is that it didn't change direction! Next frame it will try to change direction again, at infinitum. Any similar situation will result in the `KinematicBody2D` changing direction in place. It would appear to not move.

Finally, the reason why I do the `move_and_slide` before all the checks is because, `is_on_wall` and `is_on_floor` are updated when you call `move_and_slide`.

---

And this is the game running with collision shapes visible (debug option):

[image: Game recording]

As you can see, it changes direction both on a wall and on a hole.

Comment: Thank you! In the end the code was fine, i had messed up the direction of the RayCast2D thinking only the tip had to collide. Also i didn't check a box that said something like "Area collide" so that's why it wouldn't work. Now everything's smooth, thanks again!