# How do I detect collisions in Godot?

Tags: godot

I have 3 scenes. one that is named "KinematicBody2D.tscn" which a KinematicBody2D node. this scene is a player which moves from left to right across the screen. I also have a scene named "mob.tscn" which is a rigidbody2d node. this scene only has the sprite and a tiny piece of code that makes it so that the mob deletes itself once it leaves the screen using the visibility notifier(I also turned of the mask square so there would be no physic) . finally I have the main scene with has the player scene inside it and instances the mob scene every so often to spawn mobs at the top of the screen.

**I want to detect when the mob touches the player and give an output**

please explain everything very thoughrouly as I have been trying for the past couple of days to figure it out but most of the places I have looked I didn't understand what to do and when I copied the code it didn't work. some examples of things I would like to be more clear are

where and how do I add a collision shape 2d or area2d or other nodes along those lines.

where & how to connect and write the code

thank you in advance

Comment: The answer to this question demonstrates more effort (and probably quality) than >95% of the answers on this site. Please mark it as accepted if it answered your question or helped you. If it didn't, add a comment to explain why it didn't help.

Comment: @Syoma if you see this, please mark [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/131120) as such, so future answer seekers can also find it more easily, as well as search engines.

Answer (score 68):

For this answer I will start by explaining collision layers and mask. Then move on to detecting the collision. Then filtering physic bodies and communication. And I'll mention some stuff about raycast and area, and other queries at the end. *No, you don't need to know all that, but you asked for "everything very thoughrouly".*

While the question is about 2D, for 3D it is mostly the same provided you use the 3D versions of the nodes. I'll mention where it differs. On that note, just in case, know that 3D objects can't collide with 2D objects.

*If I say `Class`(`2D`/`3D`), I mean that what I'm saying applies for both `Class` and `Class2D`.*

*You will also find that I say "kinematic/character" that is referring to a kinematic body in Godot 3, or a character body in Godot 4. I'll specify when something is specific of Godot 3 or Godot 4.*

Also, since we are talking about physics, in general you will be working in [`_physics_process(…)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-physics-process). I'll mention any case when you need to write code somewhere else.

---

### Collision Layers and Collision Mask

To begin with, the default values of the `collision_layer` and `collision_mask` properties is set so that everything collides with everything.

---

Otherwise, it can be useful to define some layers. You can go to Project Settings -> General -> Layer names -> 2d Physics (or 3d Physics if you are working in 3D), and give names to the layers there.

For example, you may have layers for these (depending on the kind o game you are doing):

- The player character
- The enemy characters
- Player projectiles
- Enemy projectiles
- Collectible objects
- Ground and walls

Something like that. Then you give each physics object its own `collision_layer` depending on what they are.

In the `collision_mask` you set what they can collide with※. Sometimes it is easier to think about what they can't collide with. For example, an enemy projectile should not collide with other enemy projectiles (and telling Godot to not check for those collision can help with performance). The player character probably won't interact with player projectiles, and enemy character won't interact with enemy projectiles. Similarly, the enemy characters probably won't interact with collectibles. And everything collides with ground and walls.

※: Actually an object will collide with whatever they specify in their collision mask, and any object that specify them in their collision mask. That is, collisions are checked both ways. *That is changing for Godot 4.0.*

You have a total of 32 layers to work with. And for some people that is not enough, and we will have to resource to other ways of filtering we will see later. Regardless, try to be efficient with your layers. Use them as broad categories.

---

If you want to set the `collision_layer` and `collision_mask` properties from code, you need to keep in mind that they are sets of binary flags. I have explained that [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816495/402022).

---

### Setting up colliders

The kinematic/character, static, and rigid bodies, and also area, need `CollisionShape`(`2D`/`3D`) or `CollisionPolygon`(`2D`/`3D`) as child. Direct node children. This is what defines their size and shape as far as physics is concerned. *Adding a sprite or other graphic node is only concerned with graphics and has no effect in physics.*

If you use `CollisionShape`(`2D`/`3D`), make sure to set the `shape` to your `CollisionShape`(`2D`/`3D`). Once you picked the type of shape you want, the editor will allow you to modify it visually, or you can set its parameters in the Inspector panel.

Similarly, if you use `CollisionPolygon`(`2D`/`3D`), you need to edit the `polygon` (which is an array of points) property of your `CollisionPolygon`(`2D`/`3D`). For that the editor will allow you to draw the polygon, or you can modify the coordinates of each point in the Inspector panel.

By the way, you can have multiple of these nodes. That is, if a single `CollisionShape`(`2D`/`3D`) or `CollisionPolygon`(`2D`/`3D`) is not enough to specify the shape and size of your object, you can add more. On that note, be aware that the simpler they are the better the performance.

If you have a graphic node (e.g. a sprite), look for a tool menu that should appear on the top (to the right from "View") when you have it selected. There you can find options to generate a `CollisionShape`(`2D`/`3D`) or `CollisionPolygon`(`2D`/`3D`) from your graphic node. *I find this particularly useful with `MeshInstance` in 3D.*

A simple typical setup may look like this (2D):

*Godot 3*

```
KinematicBody2D
├ CollisionShape2D
└ Sprite
```

*Godot 4*

```
CharacterBody2D
├ CollisionShape2D
└ Sprite2D
```

Or like this (3D):

*Godot 3*

```
KinematicBody
├ CollisionShape
└ MeshInstance
```

*Godot 4*

```
CharacterBody3D
├ CollisionShape3D
└ MeshInstance3D
```

I want to emphasize that having the graphics (sprite/mesh) as children of the physics bodies is important. We will be moving the physics bodies since they interact or react with physics (so they collide with the environment), and we want the graphics to move with them. *In general the children move with the parent.*

*I go over which kind of physics body to use for common cases [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75619718/402022).*

---

### Detecting the collision

We have two objects colliding. Either of them can detect the collision.

**Note**: If in general you want to check if there is an object at a given position, see physic queries below.

---

**Detecting on a Kinematic/Character Body**

The kinematic/character body can only detect obstacles it runs into as a result of its own motion (an area is not an objstacle). That is, if another object hits it, it might not be able to detect it.

We have two approaches depending on whatever you use `move_and_collide(…)` or `move_and_slide(…)`. *We could also take advantage of an area for better detection. I'll come back to that.*

---

*`move_and_collide(…)`*

When you move the kinematic/character body using `move_and_collide(…)`, it returns a `KinematicCollision`(`2D`/`3D`) object that tells you information of what it collided with. You can get the object it collided by checking its `collider` property:

```
var collision := move_and_collide(direction * delta)
if collision != null:
    var body := collision.collider
    print("Collided with: ", body.name)
```

---

*`move_and_slide(…)`*

In the more common case you move the kinematic/character body with `move_and_slide(…)` (or `move_and_slide_with_snap(…)`). In which case you should call `get_slide_collision(slide_idx)`, which also gives us a `KinematicCollision`(`2D`/`3D`) object. ​Here is an example:

*Godot 3*

```
velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
for index in get_slide_count():
    ​var collision := get_slide_collision(index)
    var body := collision.collider
   ​ print("Collided with: ", body.name)
```

*Godot 4*

```
move_and_slide()
for index in get_slide_collision_count():
    ​var collision := get_slide_collision(index)
    var body := collision.get_collider()
   ​ print("Collided with: ", body.name)
```

*In Godot 4 `move_and_slide` takes no parameters. And `velocity` is a property of the `CharacterBody`(`2D`/`3D`).*

As you can see, we use either `get_slide_count()` in Godot 3, and `get_slide_collision_count()` in Godot 4 to figure out with how many objects the kinematic/character body collided (sliding included) in its motion. And then we get each one taking advantage of `get_slide_collision(slide_idx)`.

---

**Detecting on a Rigid Body**

To react to rigid body collision, you need to set its `contact_monitor` property to true and increase its `contacts_reported` property. That limits the number of collisions the rigid body will track. *And thus, even thought you are probably only interested on the collision with the kinematic/character body, you need to keep room for walls and floor or other collision that might be going on at the time.*

Next you are going to use the `"body_entered"` and `"body_exited"` signals. You can connect them to a script in the same rigid body (see "About connecting signals" for how to do that). The handlers would look like this:

```
func _on_body_entered(body:Node):
    print(body, " entered")

func _on_body_exited(body:Node):
    print(body, " exited")
```

Even though they are called `"body_entered"` and `"body_exited"`, you can think of them as beginning and ending contact. If you only care about the instant of collision, then you want `"body_entered"`:

```
func _on_body_entered(body:Node):
    ​print("Collided with: ", body.name)
```

---

**Detecting on an Area**

The area node is a collision object, but not a physics object. It does not push things around and thing don't push it around. Instead they pass through.

They are monitoring collision by default (controlled by the `monitoring` property), and also have `"body_entered"` and `"body_exited"` signals that you can use the same way as the ones in rigid body. You can set a `collision_mask` to control that.

Furthermore, area has `"area_entered"` and `"area_exited"` signals. That is, they can detect other areas. Which is where its `collision_layer` and `monitorable` comes in.

*I'll come back to uses of area.*

---

**Pickable**

You can also make collision objects (static, kinematic/character, rigid bodies or area) pickable with the mouse or pointing device by setting [`input_pickable`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_collisionobject2d.html#class-collisionobject2d-property-input-pickable) (or [`input_ray_pickable`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_collisionobject.html#class-collisionobject-property-input-ray-pickable) in 3D) to `true`.

Then connect the `"input_event"` signal (or override the `_input_event(…)` method) of the body or area to find out when a player clicked it.

This is how the `_input_event(…)` method would look like for a 2D node:

*Godot 3*

```
func _input_event(viewport: Object, event: InputEvent, shape_idx: int) -> void:
    pass
```

*Godot 4*

```
func _input_event(viewport: Viewport, event: InputEvent, shape_idx: int) -> void:
    pass
```

And this is how the `_input_event(…)` method would look like for a 3D node:

*Godot 3*

```
func _input_event(camera: Object, event: InputEvent, position: Vector3, normal: Vector3, shape_idx: int) -> void
    pass
```

*Godot 4*

```
func _input_event(camera: Camera3D, event: InputEvent, position: Vector3, normal: Vector3, shape_idx: int) -> void
    pass
```

*Do not confuse these with `_input`.*

---

### About connecting signals

You can connect signals from the editor, in the Node panel -> Signals tab, you will find the signals of the selected node. From there you can connect them to any node on the same scene that has a script attached. *And thus, you should have an script attached beforehand on the node you want to connect the signal to.*

Once you tell Godot to connect a signal, it will ask you to select the node you will connect it to, and allow you to specify the name of the method that will handle it (a name is generated by default). *Under "advanced" you can also add extra parameters to be passed to the method, whether or not the signal can/will wait for the next frame ("deferred"), and if it will disconnect itself once triggered ("oneshot").*

By pressing the "Connect" button, Godot will connect the signal accordingly, creating a method with the provided name in the script of the target node if it does not exist.

It is also possible to connect and disconnect signals from code. To do that use the [`connect(…)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-connect), [`disconnect(…)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-disconnect) and [`is_connected(…)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-is-connected) methods. *So you can, for example, instance a scene from code, and then use the `connect(…)` method to connect the signals to and from the instance.*

---

### Filtering physic bodies and communication

We have already been over your first tool to filter collision: collision layers and masks.

Now, by whatever means you are detecting collisions, you are getting the node the collision happened with. But you need to distinguish between them.

To do that we commonly use three types of filters:

- Filter by class.
- Filter by group.
- Filter by property.

---

**Filter by class**

To filter by class, we can use the `is` operator. For example:

*Godot 3*

```
if body is KinematicBody2D:
    print("Collided with a KinematicBody2D")
```

*Godot 4*

```
if body is CharacterBody2D:
    print("Collided with a CharacterBody2D")
```

Keep in mind this also works with user defined classes. So we can do this:

```
if body is PlayerCharacter:
    print("Collided with a PlayerCharacter")
```

Provided that we added a `const PlayerCharacter := preload("player_character.gd")` in the script. Or we added `class_name PlayerCharacter` in our player character script.

---

Another way to do this is with the `as` operator:

```
var player := body as PlayerCharacter
if player != null:
    print("Collided with a PlayerCharacter")
```

Which also gives us type safety. We can then easily access its properties:

```
var player := body as PlayerCharacter
if player == null:
    return

print(player.some_custom_property)
```

---

**Filtering by groups**

Nodes also have node groups. You can set them from the editor in the Node panel -> Groups tab. Or you can manipulate them from code with [`add_to_group(…)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-add-to-group), [`remove_from_group(…)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-remove-from-group). And, of course, we can check if an object is in a group with [`is_in_group(…)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-is-in-group):

```
if body.is_in_group("player"):
    print("Collided with a player")
```

---

**Filtering by property**

You can, of course filter by some properties for the node. For starters, its name:

```
if body.name == "Player":
    print("Collided with a player")
```

Or you could check if the `collision_layer` has a flag you are interested in:

```
if body.collision_layer & layer_flag != 0:
    print("Collided with a player")
```

It is not straightforward to get the flag from the layer name, yet possible. I found an example [elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/185955/10408).

---

**Communication**

Once you have the object identified, you probably want to interact with it. Sometimes it is a good idea to add a method (`func`) to the player character explicitly to be called by other objects that collide with it.

For example, in your player character:

```
func on_collision(body:Node) -> void:
    print("Collided with ", body.name)
```

And in your rigid body:

```
func _on_body_entered(body:Node):
    var player := body as PlayerCharacter
    if player == null:
        return

    player.on_collision(self)
```

---

You may also be interested in a signal bus, which I have explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68675270/402022).

---

### Uses of Area

You can improve upon the detection of a kinematic/character or static body by adding an area node as child. Give it the same collision shape as its parent, and connect its signals to it. That way you can get `"body_entered"` and `"body_exited"` on your kinematic/character or static body.

The setup looks something like this:

*Godot 3*

```
KinematicBody2D
├ CollisionShape2D
├ Sprite
└ Area2D
  └ CollisionShape2D
```

*With signals connected from Area2D to KinematicBody2D.*

*Godot 4*

```
CharacterBody2D
├ CollisionShape2D
├ Sprite2D
└ Area2D
  └ CollisionShape2D
```

*With signals connected from Area2D to CharacterBody2D.*

---

You can add an area to an enemy and make it larger. This is useful to define a "view cone" where enemies can detect the player. You can also combine this with raycasts to make sure the enemy has line of vision. *I recommend the video [The Easy Way to Make Enemies See in Godot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04A7pUkhx3E) by GDQuest.*

Areas also allow you to override gravity (used by rigid bodies) locally. To do that use the properties under "Physics Overrides" in the Inspector panel. They allow you to have areas where the gravity has a different direction or strength, or even make the gravity point instead of a direction.

It is also a good idea to use areas for collectible objects, which should not cause any physic reaction (no bouncing, pushing, etc), but you still need to detect when the player collides with it.

And, of course, what I would argue is the prime use of areas: you can define areas in your map that will trigger some event when the player steps on it (e.g. a door closes behind the player).

---

### RayCast

To detect collision on a `RayCast`(`2D`/`3D`), make sure its `enabled` property is set to `true`. You can also specify the `collision_mask`. And make sure to set the `cast_to` to something sensible.

The raycast will allow you to query what physics object is in the segment from its position to where `cast_to` points to (the `cast_to` vector with the transform of the raycast applied. i.e. `cast_to` is relative to the raycast).

*By the way, an infinite `cast_to` cannot work. It is not simply a performance problem. The issue is that infinite vectors don't behave well when transformed (notably when rotated).*

You can call `is_colliding()` to find out if the raycast is detecting something. And then `get_collider()` to get it. *This is updated by Godot once per physics frame.*

Example:

```
if $RayCast.is_colliding():
    print("Detected: ", $RayCast.get_collider)
```

If you need to move the raycast and detect more often than once per physics frame, you need to call `force_update_transform()` and `force_raycast_update()` on it.

*The raycast will only give you the first obstacle it encounters. If you need to find all the obstacles, you need to make a loop adding the previous obstacle as an exception. And do not forget to clear the exceptions when you no longer need them.*

---

If you want to have have enemies avoid falling from platforms, you can use raycast to detect if there is ground ahead ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087476/402022)).

---

*3D games may also use raycasts to detect what the player is looking at, or what the player clicked on. In 2D, you may want the method `intersect_point(…)` I mention below.*

*In Godot 4 you can also use `ShapeCast`(`2D`/`3D`) which works in a similar fashion, but instead of checking a ray (a point extended in a direction), checks for a volume (a shape extended in a direction).*

---

### Physic Queries

Sometimes we want to ask the Godot physics engine about stuff, without any collisions or extra nodes (such as area, raycast, or shapecast... Which will also work).

First of all, `move_and_collide(…)` has a `test_only` parameter, which, if set to `true`, will give you the collision information, but not actually move the kinematic/character body.

Second, your `RigidBody2D` have a `test_motion(…)` method that will tell you if the rigid body would collide or not given a motion vector.

But, third… We don't need a dedicated `RayCast`(`2D`/`3D`). We can do this:

- 3D: `get_world().direct_space_state.intersect_ray(start, end)`. See [`PhysicsDirectSpaceState`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_physicsdirectspacestate.html#class-physicsdirectspacestate) (Godot 3) or [`PhysicsDirectSpaceState3D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/classes/class_physicsdirectspacestate3d.html) (Godot 4).
- 2D: `get_world_2D().direct_space_state.intersect_ray(start, end)`. See [`Physics2DDirectSpaceState`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_physics2ddirectspacestate.html#class-physics2ddirectspacestate) (Godot 3) or [`PhysicsDirectSpaceState2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/classes/class_physicsdirectspacestate2d.html) (Godot 4).

In Godot 3, The 2D version of `direct_space_state` also gives you [`intersect_point(…)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_physics2ddirectspacestate.html#class-physics2ddirectspacestate-method-intersect-point) which will allow you to check what physic object is in an specific point *There is also an [`intersect_point_on_canvas(…)`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_physics2ddirectspacestate.html#class-physics2ddirectspacestate-method-intersect-point-on-canvas), which allows you to specify a canvas id, which is intended to match a [`CanvasLayer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_canvaslayer.html).*

In Godot 4, both the 2D and 3D versions of `direct_space_state` have `intersect_point`. *And `intersect_point_on_canvas` has been removed.*

And the other methods you find in `direct_space_state` are shape casts. That is, they do not check only a segment (as a raycast does) or a point (as `intersect_point(…)` does), but a shape.

---

### Tutorials and resources

See the article ["Tutorials and resources"](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/community/tutorials.html) on Godot's official documentation.

---

**A note on debugging**

While everything I said above are things to check if they are correct when something goes wrong. There are some tools and techniques for debugging to be aware of.

First of all, you can set breakpoints (with F9 or with the `breakpoint` keyword) and step through the code (F10 steps over and F11 steps into).

For debugging physics in particular you want to turn on "Visible Collision Shapes" from the debug menu.

Also, while Godot is running you can go to the Scene panel, and select the Remote tab, which will allow you to see and edit the nodes as they are on the game currently running.

You can also use the Project Camera Override option (the camera icon on the toolbar which is disabled while the game is not running) to control the camera of the running game form the editor.

And finally, you might be familiar with using `print` as a debugging tool. It allows you to log when an event happened and the values of variables. The visual equivalent would be to spawn visual objects (sprites or mesh instances) that show you when and where and event was triggered (perhaps using the color to convey extra information). Since Godot 3.5 includes `Label3D` you could use it to write some values too.

---

**A note on copying code**

Reasons why the code you copied didn't work may include that the scene tree was setup differently, or that some signal wasn't connected. However, it may also be whitespace. In GDScript whitespace is important (you can review [GDScript basics](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html)). You may have to adjust the indentation level to make it work with your code. *Also don't mix tabs and spaces, in particular in older versions of Godot.*

---

**A note on explaining problems**

So your copied code and it didn't work. What does that mean? Did it do the wrong thing or did it do nothing? Was there any error or warning? "it didn't work" isn't a good way to describe a problem.

These Q&A sites work better if you have something you are trying to solve, such some code that does not work.

I want to encourage pointing out the specific problem. Either as a new question on this or a similar site, or as a comment to the author of the answer or tutorial that is giving you trouble. *So, yes, if there is something here that is not working, tell me in the comment and I'll to improve the answer. But also go bother whoever provided the code you copied that didn't work (even if that is me again). Put some pressure on them to improve.*

Comment: thanks! this is better than most tutorials out there

Comment: What a fantastic answer!

Comment: Your explanation has given me a better answer to this problem than any I've found anywhere else, so just wanted to say thanks, especially since it's been updated for Godot 4 too  Incredible that this hasn't been accepted as the answer at this point, but there you go 

Answer (score 0):

a way i think it will work just put a area 2d on them and then you can do this on both so you just use the singal called area_entered(area) then connect that to the area 2d (make sure to make a gdsipt to connect the singal to the area 2d) then you can make the both detech both colleings

sorry for my spelling im not the best speller you can tell.

love alan

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).