# Moving my 3D Kinematic Body horizontally by setting the velocity

Tags: godot

I want to move my kinematic body horizontally by just setting the velocity but I'm keep on getting some error on this program. I'm using godot software to do this. Need a hand to help me. Below I have attached my code:

```
extends KinematicBody

var KinematicBodyWidth: int

var KinematicBodyHeight: int

var velocity: float

func _enter_tree():

    setupVelocity()

    setupKinematicBody()

    positionLeftCenter()

func _physics_process(_delta):

    move_and_slide(delta)

func move_and_slide(delta: float)-> void:

    position.x += delta * velocity
    
func setupVelocity():

    velocity = 100.0
```

Thanks and regards,
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

If you put that code on a `KinematicBody` it will give you the following error:

```
Parser Error: The function signature doesn't match the parent. Parent signature is: "Vector3 move_and_slide(Vector3, Vector3=default, bool, int, float, bool)".
```

That is because `KinematicBody` defines a `move_and_slide`. And no, you can't have an overload. GDScript does not support that. Instead creating a method with the same name is taken as an attempt to override it, which is failing when it checks if the parameters match. *The method `move_and_slide` is not virtual anyway.*

---

I also want to mention that the `slide` part of the name of `move_and_slide` refers to how it interacts with ramps. That is, if the `KinematicBody` collides with a surface that it considers a ramp, it will *slide* on it.

---

Now, you could put the code directly on `_physics_process`, like this:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    position.x += delta * velocity
```

*Notice I renamed the parameter from `_delta` to `delta`. You were passing `delta` into your `move_and_slide` method, but the parameter name was `_delta`.*

Except - wait - there is no `position` in `KinematicBody` (there is in `KinematicBody2D`), if you want to change the position you can write the origin of the transform:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    transform.origin.x += delta * velocity
```

And you need to be aware that *that* is a teleport. It would not be checking for collisions. Use `move_and_slide` (or if you don't want the `slide` part, use `move_and_collide`) that comes defined in the `KinematicBody` class. That way, it does not only moves the `KinematicBody` but also takes into account collisions.

*By the way, I would argue the variable is a speed (scalar) not a velocity (vector). Yet, I'm keeping the way you named it.*

---

Given that you have unused `KinematicBodyWidth` and `KinematicBodyHeight` I suspect you don't want to use Godot physic objects. If that is the case, you can use a regular Spatial node, and use physics queries to detect collisions.

*I have an explanation from the basics of setting up Godot physics to how to use physic queries [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022). Either if you want to use Godot physic objects and don't know how, or if you don't want to use them and use physics queries instead, I think that would help you.*

---

*The next errors are that `setupKinematicBody` and `positionLeftCenter` are not defined. Either define the methods, or remove the calls. I can't help further with those.*

---

By the way, are you sure you want to use `_enter_tree` instead of `_ready`? And are you sure you don't want to initialize velocity with the value you want (`var velocity: float = 100.0`), or you can export it so it is easy to set from the inspector panel (`export var velocity: float = 100.0`).

Your code could be just this:

```
extends KinematicBody

export var speed := 100.0

func _physics_process(delta):
    transform.origin.x += delta * speed
```

Or this:

```
extends KinematicBody

export var velocity := Vector3(100.0, 0.0, 0.0)

func _physics_process(_delta):
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```