# Godot - Game freezes when Area2D Monitoring turned on

Tags: godot, gdscript

So when my player falls off the map, I want the level to reload. I have used an area2d with a collisionshape2d to create an area that will call a function when the player collides with this area. However, when the game is run with this code included, the player will animate through a few frames then the game completely freezes before I can even move the player.

```
func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
   get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

If I delete this code, or set monitoring to off, and re-run the game it will not freeze.

Below is a screenshot of my level design.

[Level design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQXCG.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) - Is this a bug or am I doing something stupid?

When I set a breakpoint on the get_tree().reload_current_scene() line the following report shows

[debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY2hI.png)

does this mean the player is colliding with a tile - If this is the case I don't see how as the program freezes before the player touches the ground.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at the `get_tree().reload_current_scene()` line and step through your code. See if there's anything fishy like an infinite loop.

Comment: Things that come to mind: 1. An autoload causing an infinite loop, you can try stepping as hola suggests. 2. a resource that is failing to reload (e.g. music, or something else that needs to be loaded at the start), you can try to run without any suspicious resources. Also `reload_current_scene` returns a value, print it, it might give us a clue. If you go to Editor -> Open Editor Data/Settings Folder, Godot should open a folder, look into the app_userdata folder there, and then a folder matching the name of your project. You can find logs there, which may also give a clue of what is going on.

Comment: "does this mean the player is colliding with a tile - If this is the case I don't see how as the program freezes before the player touches the ground." For debugging problems with collisions, you can enable Visible Collision Shapes in the Debug Menu, which will show them on the game while debugging. You can also go to the Remote tab on the Scene panel to see the state of the nodes while the debug is paused (e.g. on a breakpoint).

Comment: @Theraot I tried adding a breakpoint on the line and stepping through. I got the report that I edited into the original post above - is this suggesting that there is a collision between the tile map and the player? As for printing the statement like you suggested Theroat, 0 is continuously outputted. As I am sure you can tell I am new to game development (This is a school project), so really appreciate you guys help.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, this line:

```
get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

Returns a value.

Now, you have said that `0` is "continuously outputted". In this context `0` means `OK`, in other words: it was able to reload the scene. The problem is the "continuously" part. It means that the scene reloads and then this code is triggered, and then it reloads again, and then this code is triggered again, and so on.

Now, apparently the `Area2D` is colliding with the `TileMap`. That makes sense. If it is a collision between the `Area2D` and a tile upon loading the scene, you would get the observed behavior. And the way the `Area2D` and `TileMap` are positioned in the scene supports the idea.

---

And about fixing it. I'll give you three solutions, either of these will work, with their drawbacks and caveats:

- Don't have the `Area2D` positioned in a way that intersects non-passable tiles. This is easy to do by moving the `Area2D` further down, or by removing any tiles that overlap it.

  The drawback with this approach is that it is fragile. You may forget in the future and move the `Area2D` or add tiles or something else that make the problem return. Also, it might not work well with your intended scenario design.
- Change the `collision_mask` and `collision_layer` in such way that the tiles and the `Area2D` do not collide. As long as the bits from the mask do not overlap the bits from the layer of the other and viceversa, Godot will not even check for a collision between them.

  The main drawback with this approach is that you have limited number of layers.

  There is also the fact that it is less intuitive that simply placing things in such a way they don't collide.

  To make it easier to work with, assign layers to different kinds of things… Go to your Project Settings, on the General Tab, under Layer Names, and 2D Physics, and give them names (e.g. "environment", "enemies", "enemy bullets", "player", "player bullets", "items", "others").

  Then you can assign to each object on `collision_layer` what they are, and on `collision_mask` set every thing they MUST collide with. With the caveat that Godot will check both ways.

  In this case you would set the `collision_layer` of the player character physics object (the `KinematicBody2D`) to "player" (or similar), and put the `collision_mask` of the `Area2D` to the same, so they collide. Have the `collision_layer` of the `TileMap` set to something else (e.g. "environment") that is not in the `collision_mask` of the `Area2D`, so the `Area2D` and the `TileMap` do not collide. And set the `collision_mask` of the player character to something that include the layer you set to the `TileMap`, so the player character also collides with it. I hope that makes sense.
- And, of course, you can filter on the `Area2D`, with a little of code. It can be checking the class, or node group, or the name of the physics body. For example you can insert at the start of the method something like this: `if body.name != "player": return`. So that it exits the method before it reaches `reload_current_scene` unless it is the correct physics body.

  The drawback with this approach is that it is still checking and registering the collision, so it has worse performance that using `collision_mask` and `collision_layer`. But it will work, and it will perform OK for a small to mid sized game.

For more complex situations, you may employ a combination of these approaches (because, as I said, there is a limited number of layers, so you need to add filtering on top of it). I have a more detailed explanation of how to setup physics objects, including the techniques mentioned here, in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022).

Comment: Thank you so much man, I have it working now . Appreciate your help.