# Godot - Enemy does not move to player when player is on the left

Tags: godot

The enemy in my game will not move towards the left when player is on the left but will move to the right. Then when the player is on the right the enemy will move to the player.

code for enemy:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var run_speed = 100
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var collider = null


func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    if collider:
        velocity = position.direction_to(collider.position) * run_speed
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)

func _on_DetectRadius_body_entered(body):
    collider = body

func _on_DetectRadius_body_exited(body):
    collider = null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using an `Area2D` and it is detecting something other than the player character. I remind you can use `collision_mask` and `collision_layer` to narrow what objects are detected. *For example, are you sure the `Area2D` is not detecting the enemy itself? For a quick check you can have Godot print the `collider` to double check it is what you expect.*

Furthermore, notice that wen an object leaves the `Area2D` it will set `collider` to `null` regardless if there is still some object inside the `Area2D` or not. I remind you that an alternative approach is using `get_overlapping_bodies`.

And, of course, you can query each `body` you get to see if it is the player character (for example by checking its node group, name, class, etc...). I go over filtering in more detail in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022).

---

If you are getting the player character, there is another possible source of problems: `position` vs `global_position`. The code you have like this:

```
position.direction_to(collider.position)
```

Is correct if both the enemy and the `collider` it got have the same parent. In that case their positions are in the same space. Otherwise, you may want to either work on global coordinates:

```
global_position.direction_to(collider.global_position)
```

Or you can bring the `collider` position to local coordinates:

```
position.direction_to(to_local(collider.global_position))
```

---

And of course, double check that the `Area2D` is positioned correctly. You can enable "Visible Collision Shapes" on the "Debug" menu, which will show it when running the game from the editor.