# Area2D Not Triggering Object in Godot

Tags: godot

Here is my code: (just so you know I am a beginner and I just started this week, though I do have knowledge with other languages and game engines)

```
func _on_Area2D_area_entered(area):
    get_parent().get_node("Level 1/Area2D/Flag").rotation_degrees += 1
```

What I was trying to accomplish was that the Player GameObject would see if its in the area of the Flag, and if it is, the flag would rotate.

I am not sure where the issue is. I think it is probably in the second line. I provided a screenshot below if I did the setup wrong. I have looked at the other close questions asked on the same topic, but they did not answer my question.

[image]

The "Player" GameObject is the one with the script that contains the detection if its in the area2D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to check if the `Area2D` is positioned correctly during runtime enable Debug -> Visible Collision Shapes.

If you want to check if `_on_Area2D_area_entered` is running, add breakpoints (or use print).

---

Did you get an error?

If there isn't a `Node` there, this expression will cause an error in runtime:

```
get_parent().get_node("Level 1/Area2D/Flag")
```

If you want to be able to check, you can use [`get_node_or_null`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-get-node-or-null) and [`is_instance_valid`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-is-instance-valid).

*Since you didn't mention any error, I'm going to guess the method is not running.*

---

If the method is not running, the most likely culprit is that - I'm guessing given then name of the method - you connected the `"area_entered"` signal but intended to connect the `"body_entered"` signal.

The `"area_entered"` signal will trigger when another `Area2D` enters the `Area2D`. But I only see one `Area2D` in your scene tree. On the other hand the `"body_entered"` will trigger when a `PhysicsBody2D` (e.g `StaticBody2D`, `KinematicBody2D`, `RigidBody2D`) enters the `Area2D`. In either case you get what entered as a parameter of the method.

Other reasons why the `Area2D` might not be detecting what you want include no intersection of `collision_layer` and `collision_mask` and `monitoring` being disabled.

---

And to dismiss a couple possible misconceptions:

- The `"area_entered"` and `"body_entered"` trigger when the `Area2D` or `PhysicsBody2D` respectively enter the `Area2D`, not every frame they are inside. *So `rotation_degrees += 1` is not a rotation animation.*
- You will get notifications of anything that trigger the signals, not just the object to which you connected it. You may have to further filter, e.g. `if body == self:`.

---

*For people arriving here from search, I want to link a similar case: [Enemy is not affected by bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72774189/402022). And also my [full explanation of how to set up physic nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022).*

Comment: you are correct. I have figured out that I didn't have area2d on my player so I changed it to body. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: also, I could easily make an bool activated, and when its activated it runs a loop in a delta func

Comment: tnx thousand times mate!