# Examples of using body_entered and body_exited in Godot 3D (version 3.4.4)

Tags: collision, godot, gdscript

I am trying to make a teleport part, so I need to detect when Body collides with area. I tried to use `body_enter`/`body_entered` and `body_exit`/`body_exited`, but I do not know how *exactly* they work and where do I need to insert them. Can I have example codes of using it?
My nodes path:

```
RigidBody
├ CollisionShape
├ MeshInstance
├ Area
├ ├ CollisionShape
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I detect collision between a kinematicbody 2d(player) node and a rigidbody2d node(mob) in Godot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69728827/how-do-i-detect-collision-between-a-kinematicbody-2dplayer-node-and-a-rigidbod)

Comment: No, it don't works for 3D I guess. I insert this in script, but it does nothing. Here is what my path looks like:
RigidBody --> CollisionShape --> Area --> CollisionShape

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Scene tree structure**

First of all, if you want two things to collide you probably want them to be **siblings**. *Not one `Node` child of the other.* This is because `Spatial`s are placed relative to their parent. Said another way: when an `Spatial` moves, its children move with it.

---

**Enable monitoring**

Second, you want to make sure that the `Node` that will detect the collision is able to do it. In the case of a `RigidBody` and an `Area`, the `Area` will detect the `RigidBody`, and for that it must have `monitoring` to be `true` *This is the default. Thus, unless you have been messing with it, you need to do nothing.*

---

**Layers and masks**

Third, you want the layers and masks to overlap. In particular, you want the `collision_mask` of the `Area` to have bits in common with the `collision_layer` of the `RigidBody`. *By default, they come with the first bit set, so this is also satisfied by default unless you have been messing with it.*

---

**SIGNALS**

Fourth, you need to **connect** the `"body_entered"` signal of the `Area`. You have two ways to do that:

- Using the editor:

  Have the `Area` selected in the Scene panel (on the left by default), and then go to the Node panel (on the right by default) and then to the Signals tab.

  There you should find "body_entered(body:Node)". Double click it. *Or select it and then click the "Connect…" button at the bottom, or press enter.*

  Godot will ask you to select the `Node` you will connect it to. You can connect it to any `Node` on the same scene that has a script attached beforehand. *I suggest to connect it to the `Area` itself.*

  Godot will also allow you to specify the name of the method that will handle it (by default the name will be `_on_Area_body_entered`).

  *Under "advanced" you can also add extra parameters to be passed to the method, whether or not the signal can/will wait for the next frame ("deferred"), and if it will disconnect itself once triggered ("oneshot").*

  By pressing the Connect button, Godot will connect the signal accordingly, creating a method with the provided name in the script of the target node if it does not exist.
- From code:

  To connect a signal from code you use the [connect](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-connect) method. *See also [disconnect](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-disconnect) and [is_connected](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-is-connected).*

  So you can, use the `connect` method to connect the `"body_entered"` signal, like this:

  ```
  func _ready() -> void:
      connect("body_entered", self, "_on_Area_body_entered")

  func _on_Area_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
      pass
  ```

  This code is intended to work in a script attached to the `Area` itself. *It is also possible to call `connect` from a `Node` to another.* Please note that we are passing the name of the method we want to connect as parameter to the `connect` method, and thus it can be whatever you want.

  *The `connect` method has optional parameters to specify extra parameters, or if you want the connection to be deferred or oneshot.*

To reiterate: simply adding a method won't work, you need to connect the signal to it. And there is no special name for the method, it can have any name you choose.

---

With that done, the method should execute when the `RigidBody` overlaps the `Area`.

Comment: I think this code don't work because I use VehicleBody. Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @ColorfulYoshi That should not matter. I don't know if you have connected the signal. where or how. You should see a green icon next to the method if it is connected from the editor. I'm also going to suggest to 1: set a breakpoint inside the method so the debugger stops if and when the method runs. and 2. Enable "Visible Collision Shapes" from the debug menu, so you can see the colliders while running the game form the editor. Also, did the game output any errors while running? (if you used `connect` and it failed, there would be an error - in that case try printing what `connect` returns).

Comment: So I printed out what ```connect``` returns, it returns 0. I enabled Visibile Collision Shapes, and drive into part. It does nothing. Maybe I'm writing script in incorrect node? Where do I need to insert it? In my character or in the object what player need to collide?

Comment: @ColorfulYoshi `0` means OK. It must have connected. Did you try with a breakpoint inside the method? You can add a breakpoint via the script editor by selecting a code line and pressing F9 (by default), or by clicking left of the line numbers. If you set the breakpoint from the editor you should see a red dot there.  Or you can add a breakpoint by writing the `breakpoint` keyword in the code. Either way, when running from the editor, the execution would stop (break) when it reaches that point. If it does not, we have to figure out why. But if it does, the issue is the code inside the method.

Comment: @ColorfulYoshi The `"body_entered"` should trigger when another body collides or overlaps. Now, the `Area` is not a body. Using the `"body_entered"` of the `RigidBody` or `VehicleBody` to detect the `Area` would not work. Which is why I was saying in the answer to place it on the `Area`. We want the `Area` to detect the `RigidBody`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I just was writing script in ```RigidBody```, not in the ```Area```.

Comment: @ColorfulYoshi Put the breakpoint inside the method. I mean inside `_on_Area_body_entered`. I wrote it with a `pass` in the answer, which does nothing. The idea is to check if the problem is that code (Either `pass` or something else you might have put there), or if the problem is that the execution is not reaching that point at all. *For that goal, adding a `print` would also work.* If it is reaching that point, then you can go ahead and change the code with what you want to happen. Otherwise, well, I don't know, something else is up.