# Area2D collision isn't registered in Godot

Tags: game-physics, game-engine, game-development, godot, physics-engine

I've been trying to make pong in Godot and I got this problem. Just to be clear i only have Area2Ds and do not have any RigidBody. I've tried using print as debug but it doesn't work, I've even tried "set_monitoring(true)" and it still doesn't work, please help. This is the project:
[https://github.com/lucaross06/Godot-Pong](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSnRY.png](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: You need to connect the signals. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used godot in awhile, but I remember this. You do need to check the area2d node's collision mask and make sure this is on the layers the objects you want to collider with are on. To do this you must click on the node and then expand collision under CollisionsObject2d. Then, the mask where it checks for collisions. The layer is where the object is. Click on the right one and it should start collidering. Hope this works have a nice day.