# How Dynamically Creating Obstacles and Collision Detection in Godot 4?

Tags: godot, godot4

I’m currently working on a project in Godot 4 and I need help with dynamically creating obstacles and implementing collision detection for them. I want to be able to detect collisions with these dynamically created obstacles.

Here are the key points of my question:

Dynamically Creating Obstacles:

I want to generate obstacles programmatically during runtime.
What is the best way to create obstacles dynamically in Godot 4?
Collision Detection:

I need to implement collision detection for these dynamically created obstacles.
How can I set up collision detection for dynamically generated objects?
Detecting Collisions:

Once collision detection is set up, how can I detect when other objects collide with these dynamically created obstacles?
Are there any specific methods or signals in Godot 4 that I should use for collision detection?

If possible, could someone provide code snippets or examples illustrating how to create obstacles dynamically and implement collision detection in Godot 4?
Any guidance, tips, or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You seem to be trying to do too much at once. Break the problem down... Have you been able to create obstacles NOT DYNAMICALLY? Have you been able to instantiate scenes in runtime? - "How can I set up collision detection for dynamically generated objects?" The same way you do for not dynamically generated objects. Are there any specific methods or signals in Godot 4 that I should use for collision detection? Yes, see [How do I detect collisions in Godot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022)