# My instantiated enemies don't do anything I tell them to. (godot)

Tags: instance, instantiation, godot, multiple-instances, gdscript

So, I'm making a top down shooter, and I want to infinitely instantiate enemies to chase the player. When I instantiate the enemy, it just appears on the screen and does none of the code i put in the enemy script. here is the main lvl script: the enemy is it's child.

```
extends Node2D

var enemy_scene = preload("res://level/enemies/zombie.tscn")

func _ready():
    pass 

func _on_timer_timeout():
    spawn_enemy()

func spawn_enemy():
    var enemy_instance = enemy_scene.instantiate() as CharacterBody2D
    enemy_instance.position = get_enemy_position()
    enemy_instance.visible = true
    add_child(enemy_instance)

func get_enemy_position():
    var spawn_x = randf_range($player.position.x + 100.0, $player.position.x - 100.0)
    var spawn_y = randf_range($player.position.y + 100.0, $player.position.y - 100.0)
    return Vector2(spawn_x, spawn_y)
```

there is a 3 second timer which instantiates a enemy, but it doesn't do ANYTHING i've tried coding it to do. I can use the variable "enemy instance" to do basic stuff, like setting visability to true, but if I want to do something every frame, thats a problem.

I've tried to watch youtube toturials, which for some reason, they did the same thing as me, and the instantiations still worked. I even asked GPT, who was of no use.

Answer (score 0):

---

### Create a Zombie Class

It is either a good idea or it is necessary to give a script to the root of the `zombie.tscn` class. So let us start there...

Create an script, I'll call it `zombie.gd`, which you attach to the root of the `zombie.tscn` scene.

That `zombie.gd` must extend `CharacterBody2D` since that is the type of node the root of the `zombie.tscn` scene is:

*`zombie.gd`*

```
extends CharacterBody2D
```

You can also give it a class name so we can use that as a type globally:

*`zombie.gd`*

```
class_name Zombie
extends CharacterBody2D
```

---

### Make the Zombies move on their own

In that script you can define `_physics_process` which will run every physics frame, and `_process` which will rune every graphics frame (The `delta` argument will have the time in seconds since the last frame of its kind):

*`zombie.gd`*

```
class_name Zombie
extends CharacterBody2D


func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    print(delta)


func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    print(delta)
```

So you can use these to have your `Zombie` do something every frame.

Notably, being a `CharacterBody2D`, you probably want to call `move_and_slide` on `_physics_process`.

---

I'll also assume you want them to chase the player character. This is what comes to mind:

You can add an `Area2D` as a child to the `Zombie` with a collision shape that defines the area within which the `Zombie` will detect the player character.

For that detection you can connect the `body_entered` signal to the root of the `zombie.tscn` scene, adding a new method in the the `zombie.gd` script that looks somthing like this:

*`zombie.gd`*

```
func _on_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
    pass
```

So you can get a reference to the body it detected:

*`zombie.gd`*

```
var maybe_player_character:Node2D

func _on_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
    maybe_player_character = body as Node2D
```

You might want to confirm it is the player character. We might do this by giving also a script with a class name to the player character scene (similar to how we gave `Zombie` to the `zombie.tscn` scene. For example if that class is `PlayerCharacter` we can do this:

*`zombie.gd`*

```
var player_character:PlayerCharacter

func _on_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
    var maybe_player_character := body as PlayerCharacter
    if is_instance_valid(maybe_player_character):
        player_character = maybe_player_character
```

*I'm going to defer you to [How do I detect collisions in Godot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022) for details*

---

Then using `global_position` of the `Zombie` and the player character you can pick the direction to move, and export a variable for the speed (you set it in the Inspector dock):

*`zombie.gd`*

```
@export var speed:float


func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    if not is_instance_valid(player_character):
        return

    var direction := global_positition.direction_to(
        player_character.global_positition
    )

    velocity = direction * speed
    move_and_slide()
```

The behavior of the zombies could be more complex, of course, but with this you have zombies that do something.

---

Presumably you also want to handle the case of the zombies colliding with the player character. Again please refer to [How do I detect collisions in Godot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022). And presumably you also want some kind of damage/health/lives... While that is beyond the scope of this question, here is a hint: you can add a `health` property to the `PlayerCharacter` class.

---

### A Director telling the Zombies what to do

You seem to want your spawner script to not only spawn the enemies, but also to control them. I'll continue to call it spawner for the sake of this answer, but know what you would be making is a director.

Let us start by using the `Zombie` class in your spawner:

*spawner*

```
var enemy_instance := enemy_scene.instantiate() as Zombie
```

So if you define additional properties or methods in your `zombie.gd`, you can access them from your spawner. For example:

*`zombie.gd`*

```
class_name Zombie
extends CharacterBody2D


var another_property:int
```

*spawner*

```
var enemy_instance := enemy_scene.instantiate() as Zombie
enemy_instance.another_property = 42
```

Or:

*`zombie.gd`*

```
class_name Zombie
extends CharacterBody2D


func my_method() -> void:
    print("my_method called")
```

*spawner*

```
var enemy_instance := enemy_scene.instantiate() as Zombie
enemy_instance.my_method()
```

To be clear, you could call any method, including `move_and_slide`, not just the ones you defined.

---

You can add paramters to the method, for example:

*`zombie.gd`*

```
class_name Zombie
extends CharacterBody2D


func my_method(something:String) -> void:
    print(something)
```

*spawner*

```
var enemy_instance := enemy_scene.instantiate() as Zombie
enemy_instance.my_method("Director says hello")
```

This can be a way to give information to the zombies, such as the position of the player, or tell them to stop chasing, etc.

---

If you need to call something on the zombies after you created them, you are going to need to keep a reference to them. One way would be to keep a list of the instances you created (which you also need to maintain to remove any no longer valid instances, such as zombies the player destroyed)...

But since you are adding the instances as children:

```
add_child(enemy_instance)
```

We could use the list of children to do this instead.

So if you want to call something on all of them, you could iterate over all the children, for example:

*spawner*

```
func _process(_delta:float) -> void:
    for child in get_children():
        var zombie := child as Zombie
        if not is_instance_valid(zombie):
            continue

        zombie.my_method("Director says hello")
```

---

Another option could be to put the root of the `zombie.tscn` scene on a node group (You find this in the Groups tabs of the Node dock), for example, let us say they are in the `"zombie"` group, so you can do this:

*spawner*

```
func _process(_delta:float) -> void:
    get_tree().call_group(&"zombie", &"my_method", "Director says hello")
```

---

Node communication is an iceberg. There are other approaches for telling your nodes to do something, notably using signals. But without more context of what are you trying to do, the above ones are the ones I'm willing to suggest.

Comment: what if I wanted the instantiated zombies to also chase me, without an area. I suppose I would do that in a process delta function, but how would I call that from the spawner or just make the instantiations of the zombie just run process delta when they spawn?

Comment: @oliverjames They need to get a reference to the player character somehow. You could use an autoload to store a reference to the player character so everybody can get it from there, or you you could add the player character to a node group and then use `get_nodes_in_group` or something. Addendum: I'll give you an example were you would want to use a director: an stealth game when the player triggers alarts, the director can send enemies their way. Unless you need stuff like that, you can have your enemies do their own behaviors.

Comment: I'm sorry for being a hassle, I'm still not really sure how the zombies are supposed to move on their own. I've tried just making the zombies move downwards. (zombie.gd: _process(delta):    position.y + 5), but the zombies just spawn there motionless, Even when I make them just look at the mouse pointer, they do nothing. I might need to just know the concept of making zombies do stuff first, or at least, making instantiations run script every frame like moving. Leave aside all the reference of the players. I still can't make the zombies do basic things.

Comment: @oliverjames are `_process`/`_physics_process` executing? I had them use `print` to begin with in the answer, which is a way you can confirm. If they are not running, they can't move the zombie. Make sure you attached `zombie.gd` the script to the root of the `zombie.tscn` scene. You can also check `process_mode` is not set to diabled in the inspector. Since `_process` and `_physics_process`  are virtual, they should get a blue icon, just like the one on `_ready`. Are you getting any error or warning?